# .htaccess redirect: Capture portion of URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, capture

Given the following URL:

```
www.example.com/old/items/itemid/detail
```

Now say I want to redirect requests for that to the following location:

```
www.example.com/new/product/location/itemid
```

...where 'itemid' is, of course, dynamic but will always be a sequence of exactly four numbers.

How do I create a redirect rule in .htaccess that will "capture" the 'itemid' from the original URL and redirect to the new location with the same itemid at the end of the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^old/items/(\d*)/detail$ /new/product/locations/$1 [L,R=301]
```

should work but I haven't tried it. Basically, `(\d*)` matches an arbitrary length of digits and that match can be re-used using `$1`.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. Your solution worked great without a trailing slash after 'detail', but failed when one was added. So I added the slash to the RewriteRule and now it works with or without the slash in the URL.

Thank you again!